# Discrepancies between the api url and the original one on collegescorecard?

Tags: data-request, api, collegescorecard

There seem to be some discrepancies (Or maybe I did something wrong) between the data retrieved from the api url: https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools and from calling the original url: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov on a web browser.

For example, I tried to do a search via java using the api url for schools with the zip code 13902 and radius 2 miles and I got 2 results. But if you do the same thing on a web browser using the original url, it returns nothing. Can someone explain this to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to the fact that some of the institutions for which data are provided for in the API, do not appear in the consumer website.  The consumer website includes predominantly associate’s and bachelor’s awarding schools (PREDDEG=2 , PREDDEG=3). In addition, the Department recently added institutions to the consumer site such that institutions that predominantly award certificates (PREDDEG=1) are included IF the highest degree is at least an Associate's (HIGHDEG>=2 ) AND the institution offers an associate's or bachelor's degree (CIPxxASSOC>0 OR CIPxxBACHL>0).  All other institutions are not included on the consumer website.

Comment: whats behind the decision to keep data.gov updated and not the data's site? i wasn't even aware data.gov housed any data...thought it was a repo of metadata regarding data stored elsewhere....

Comment: api.data.gov is an API management service for federal agencies. It acts as a layer above our existing APIs, handling API keys, rate limiting, and gathering usage stats. Also, by providing a standard entry point to participating APIs, it's easier for developers to explore and use APIs across the federal government.  Collegescorecard.ed.gov is powered on the backend by api.data.gov. There is only one copy of the data that is used by the API, and in turn the consumer website